# Deleting file if exist via Jenkins Windows Batch Command

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins build step using Windows Batch Command. In this step I want to delete a file if exists. Here is what I have tried:

%Branch% is environment variable

First Try

```
IF "%Branch%" == "dev" (
      
  -- Run SonarQube scanner here that creates SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets file

  -- delete file if exists
  SET MYFILE = "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets"
   IF EXIST %MYFILE%
   (
     DEL /F %MYFILE% 
     REM SonarQube Target File Deleted
   )
)
```

Second Try

```
IF "%Branch%" == "dev" (

  -- Run SonarQube scanner here that creates SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets file

  -- delete file if exists
   IF EXIST "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets"
   (
     DEL /F "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets" 
     REM SonarQube Target File Deleted
   )
)
```

in both approaches I am getting syntax error at IF EXIST

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> D:\Jenkins\myproject\workspace>IF EXIST

Comment: You can't just freeform where you are going to put the parentheses when using a command block.  For some reason you decided to do it correctly with the outer `IF` command but decided to not do it correctly with the inner `IF` command.

Comment: Also, in your "FIRST TRY" the syntax is incorrect for the `SET` command and it also requires the usage of delayed expansion because you are defining a variable inside a command block and then trying to use it within that same parenthesized command block.

Comment: `SET MYFILE = "…"` sets a variable called `MYFILE` + _space_ to a value _space_ + `"…"`; you should therefore use `set MYFILE=…` or, even better, `set "MYFILE=…"`, to assign the value `…` to the variable called `MYFILE`…